# When you create a new conda environment, does it automatically include all packages in /usr/local/anaconda3/pkgs?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

I installed several conda packages in `/usr/local/pkgs`, and created a new environment with `conda create --name env1`. Will this environment by default include all the packages in `/usr/local/pkgs`, or will it include only the packages that are shipped by default with conda? Also, where can I see the list of packages that are included in a given environment? I'm using OS X.

Comment: It shouldn't. What if you have an environment with an entirely different version of python?

Comment: Understood. Fortunately there's only one package, pytorch, that I want to include. So I'd create a new environment using `conda create -n env1 pytorch`, does that sound right?

Comment: That sounds exactly right

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. If you want it to, you can use

```
conda create --name env1 --clone base
```

But it's generally not recommended to clone **base** since it includes additional packages only **base** needs.

You can check what is installed in an env with

```
conda list --name env1
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense. So there are packages included in the base env that are needed in order for it to be the base env, but wouldn't be required in an env I create myself?

Comment: @RNdev yes, exactly. Specifically, all the Conda infrastructure. Note there are metapackages that install a bunch of packages, like `anaconda` and `r-essentials`. It just depends on how fine-grained you want to be and whether or not you care about installing things you won't need.

Answer (score 2):

you can list all the packages installed with `conda list` once the environment is activated

```
conda activate envname    
conda list
```

The packages in the base environment wont be available in environments by default